# TFS 2017 - Show Areas in Work Backlog Boards

Tags: tfs, project-management

I am trying to use Areas to divide up work on a project, but the default backlogs in TFS 2017 don't show any items assigned to Areas that are not the default root Area.

Project

==Default Area

====Client 1 Sub-Area

======Epics, Stories, etc.

====Client 2 Sub-Area

======Epics, Stories, etc.

All of the items in the sub-areas disappeared from all Boards. Queries still work, but the view is list view only. I need to be able to show all of the team's work on one board, and even better if the Areas become swimlanes on the Board.

There does not appear to be a way to alter the query used by the Backlogs, nor is there a way to show a Board for custom queries. How can I show Items from all Areas on a Board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to the team project Work setting page. click the blue words "click here".
   [image]
2. In the team setting Area page, click "Select area(s)", then add those sub-areas. The selected area paths will determine what shows up on your team's backlog and what work items your team is responsible for.

[image]

Comment: That was easy! I'd been digging through the settings for a week and searching visualstudio.com to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TingTings answer:

Instead of selecting the sub areas one by one you can also use the context menu of the parent area to include all sub areas.